# Recent call date & latest agent name

Tags: powerquery

**Problem statement**: For a particular "Id" how can I choose first call date & name of agent who has called recently

**Desired output**: For Eg: here first call date for id 16468 would be 02-01-2023 & agent who has called recently would be ANGEL which is based on recent call date for that particular id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKNHY.png) Current scenario

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKaOA.png) Desired output

How can I get above desired output in power query code ?

I tried to create distinct "Id" table and separate Date table with this code but I am not able to display first call date & agent name who has called recently against each distinct "Id"

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Id", Int64.Type}, {"call date", type datetime}, {"Agent name", type text}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type",{{"call date", type date}}),
    
    Unique_Tablerows = Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type1", "Id")),
    DateOnly_Table = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type1", "call date")
    
    
in
    DateOnly_Table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below. Next time please past samples as text not images

Note your sample output is confused based on your request, since if you are looking for an ID you cant have that repeat twice

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"call date", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Id"}, {
    {"call date", each List.Min([call date]), type nullable date},
    {"Agent name", each Table.LastN(Table.Sort(_,{{"call date", Order.Ascending}}),1){0}[Agent name], type text}
})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]